# Django Performance, Slow TTFB Without Any Queries

Tags: python, django, performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a simple view which renders an HTML template. **No variables whatsoever and no database queries**. However, my **TTFB is still 665ms**.

Here is code for the view:

```
def test_page(request):
    return render(request, 'home/test_page.html')
```

The template `home/test_page.html` is a **12.5 KB file.**

I'm using an Amazon EC2 instance (**t2.medium**) deployed with Elastic Beanstalk. **Django version 1.8 using python 3.4.**

Since I'm using Elastic-Beanstalk, The configuration of the server is done by AWS.

An interesting observation is that a smaller file such as a **4.1 KB file gives me a TTFB of 145ms.**

Comment: I'd remove all template rendering and send the simplest 200 response to get a baseline, then read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/performance/.

Comment: A plain 200 response takes 24.31 ms. I've read that particular page in great detail and tried pretty much everything suggested except for switching to jinja2, which I think would be overkill.

Comment: Are you running DEBUG mode (which suppresses the cached template loader)? Also, maybe investigate impact of different EC2 instance type (with more CPU and more RAM)?

Comment: I went all the way up to an m3.xlarge instance, no improvement. I started a new Django project, and the situation described in my original question takes roughly 50ms. So, it probably has nothing to do with the server setup... I tried disabling all the extra middlewares as well... still nothing.

Comment: Did u get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with an HTML minify middleware.

Here is where the issue is discussed: https://github.com/cobrateam/django-htmlmin/issues/53

Comment: Was this fix released?